# Arrow key press statement not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple gallery for a web page which consists of the user pressing their left and right arrow keys taking them the previous/next image. So far I have the code shown below. It doesn't seem to respond to key presses though. I've checked the console and there are no errors, leaving me stuck as to what the issue is.

The .image div html does not change on key press - any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1;
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        if (current == 1) {
            var current = 1;
        } else {
            var current = current - 1;
        }
        $('.image').html('<img src="images/' + current + '.jpg"/>');
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        var current = current + 1;
        $('.image').html('<img src="images/' + current + '.jpg"/>');
    }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

*I've tweaked it, the current variable was resetting on keydown. The OP has been edited - this leaves me with the problem of the current variable lisitng NaN.jpg as file names?*

Comment: Can you put together an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Based on the code, `e.keyCode` is obviously not 37 or 39.  So, what value are you receiving?  This should give you an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSd/

Comment: I've tweaked it, the current variable was resetting on keydown. The OP has been edited - this leaves me with the problem of the current variable lisitng NaN.jpg as file names?

Comment: `current.toString()` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `current` being undefined is a result of you redefining current in various scopes of your code. This is a tricky programming bug called variable shadowing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

You should define your variable current in one scope, then reference it in lower scope like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1;
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        alert(current); 
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        if (current == 1) {
            current = 1;
        } else {
            current = current - 1;
        }
        $('.image').html('<img src="images/' + current + '.jpg"/>');
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        current = current + 1;
        $('.image').html('<img src="images/' + current + '.jpg"/>');
    }
    });
});
```

see this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RTWM6/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSd/1/

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
var current = 1;
if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    console.log('left arrow');
    if (current == 1) {
        current = 1;
    } else {
        var current = current - 1;
    }
    $('.image').html('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>');
}
else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    console.log('right arrow');
    var current = current + 1;
    $('.image').html('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>');
}
});
```